# Variable in MediaWiki for the current user

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

In MediaWiki, you can use a variable ("Magic Word") such as

```
{{PAGENAME}}
```

or

```
{{REVISIONDAY}}
```

to get specific information related to the current page being viewed. Is there a similar variable (or perhaps a different way) to get the current user who is logged in to the wiki, i.e. something like

```
{{USERNAME}}
```

*context: Trying to use the #ask query in Semantic MediaWiki to narrow the list of resulting pages to show those only the user has created or edited:*

```
{{#ask: [[Case Reflection:+]] [[Contributing User::{{USERNAME}}]]
 | format=template
 | template=Case Reflection Form Summary
 | link=all
 | sort=Last Edited
 | order=DESC
 | default=You have no case reflections related to this Case Study.}}
```

Comment: If someone is looking for the variable of this in the code base, it's the global `$wgUser` object. (That's how I bumped into this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a bunch of extensions for that such as [GetUserName](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aGetUserName), [MyVariables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMyVariables), [UserInfo](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aUserInfo). The whole concept of showing usernames is incompatible with page caching though (you need to parse the page again every time someone looks at it) so generally not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, I used [Extension:MyVariables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMyVariables) and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was just searching for the same thing, and looking to see if I could do it without extensions.  It looks like there's a default feature that allows this, *as long as you want it as part of writing a static version to a page,* not to say "Hello, Username!"  (That last case is why they have not implemented it as a standard variable, because it causes caching problems.)

[Wikimedia feature request T14733](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T14733) resolves with:

```
{{subst:REVISIONUSER}}
```

{{REVISIONUSER}} will dynamically show the last editor, which is usually not what you want. But if you want, for example, to make a template that includes the user's handle as part of some inserted text, this should do the job.  I think in your example above,

```
[[Contributing User::{{subst:REVISIONUSER}}]]
```

(I'm not sure if Semantic Mediawiki will make you escape out the substitutions, but if it does, further instructions are at [Manual:Substitution, Multilevel substitution section](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Substitution#Multilevel_substitution).)